# Phone tricks and hidden layouts

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I have an iPhone 8 plus and I'm trying to make it. So I have a different Home Screen when other people use my phone. And I'm trying to see if I can jail. Break my iPhone 8 plus and have the ability to make the phone. Know what user is using the phone currently through facial recognition or something? So if I'm not using my phone, it knows and recognizes it and.  Shows a different layout or background than it would when myself. The administrative user is using the phone